# Java - number of hours round up to 1

Tags: java

I'm working on an excercise about car parking. Once car is parked for even 5 minutes, it needs to pay for full 1 hour. So I'm looking to receive int 1 from code below, but I'm getting a 0. Some hints?

```
GregorianCalendar data1 = new GregorianCalendar(2015,1,4,11,10);
GregorianCalendar data2 = new GregorianCalendar(2015,1,4,11,20);   
long b =(data2.getTimeInMillis()-data1.getTimeInMillis())/1000/3600;
int k=(int)Math.ceil(b);
System.out.println(k);
```

Comment: use Math.ceil(double a) instead of floor.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: where is date3 initiazed?

Comment: Did you look up what `Math.floor` does?

Comment: I had some editting error, which I corrected. Yes I know what ceil and math do, but both return 0 for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianCalendar data1 = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 1, 4, 11, 10);
        GregorianCalendar data2 = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 1, 4, 11, 20);
        double b = (data2.getTimeInMillis() - data1.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000.0 * 3600.0);
        System.out.println(b);
        int k = (int) Math.ceil(b);
        System.out.println(k);
    }
```

**output**

```
0.16666666666666666
1
```

brush your [Math function here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/function-floor-ceiling.html), really very well explained by the author.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
GregorianCalendar data1 = new GregorianCalendar(2015,1,4,11,10);
GregorianCalendar data2 = new GregorianCalendar(2015,1,4,11,20);   
double b =(data2.getTimeInMillis()-data1.getTimeInMillis())/1000.0/3600.0;
double k=Math.ceil(b);
System.out.println(k);
```

You want to use `Math.ceil()` and work in `double` so you can store decimal places. Otherwise when you do subtraction and divide by `3600`, you may end up with `450 / 3600` and with a `long`, you will end up with `0`, and hence why you kept getting `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite your code to something like that

```
GregorianCalendar data1 = new GregorianCalendar(2015,1,4,11,10);
GregorianCalendar data2 = new GregorianCalendar(2015,1,4,11,20);
// b must be float   
float b =(data2.getTimeInMillis()-data1.getTimeInMillis())/1000;
b = b /3600;
int k=(int)Math.ceil(b);
return k;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thinks:

1. b must be a double. Because if you devide the difference by 1000 and 3600 b is not langer a long value. it is a floting pot value (0.16666666666666666);
2. Use Math.ceil instead of Math.floor.

[Math.floor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double))

> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that
>   is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical
>   integer

this will return 0

[Math.ceil](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double))

> Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.

this will return 1 because 1 is the next bigger integer

Answer (score 0):

Here a verbose and self-explaining example. It also handle the case if the `endTime` is before `startTime` (for what ever reason).

```
GregorianCalendar startTime = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 1, 4, 11, 10);
GregorianCalendar endTime = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 1, 4, 11, 20);
long parkingTimeMillis = startTime.getTimeInMillis() - endTime.getTimeInMillis();
long hoursToPay = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(parkingTimeMillis) + 1;
System.out.println(hoursToPay);
```

Answer (score 0):

using long b is making output to 0. Use double or float. Long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement **integer**. So whatever you do in RHS it will result in an integer rounded-off. So lets say you perform:

```
System.out.println((long) 1.9);
```

output of it will be 1 instead of 1.9.

So try by doing

```
float b = (float) ((data2.getTimeInMillis() - data1.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000) / 3600;
```